# Why does recursive routing happen?

Tags: routing, tunnel

According to:
https://study-ccnp.com/gre-tunnels-recursive-routing-problems/

> Recursive routing occurs when the router learns the destination IP
> address for the tunnel interface through the tunnel itself. It removes
> the previous entry for the tunnel destination IP address from the
> routing table, making the tunnel’s destination inaccessible.

Why is that?
Why can't the tunnel's endpoint be reached using the tunnel encapsulation?
Why does this actually drop the connection?

Please explain step by step why this phenomenon happens.

Please don't tell me in general - "You can't send the tunnel's control traffic via the tunnel since it will collapse the tunnel."

Comment: A [good explanation can be found here](https://networkjutsu.com/gre-tunnel-recursive-routing/)

Comment: Also [this](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5990/stuck-at-gre-troubleshooting-with-recursive-route?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

As the joke goes... *Everything has a beginning and an end, except sausage, it has two (ends.)*

A tunnel has two endpoints: a source and a destination, which will be mirrored at the other end. (From device A, the source is one of A's addresses [1.1.1.1], and the destination one of B's addresses [2.2.2.2]. From B, the two are swapped.)

It should go without saying you cannot reach either endpoint of the tunnel **through** the tunnel itself. Before the tunnel is up, there will be no active routes pointing traffic into the tunnel. Thus either the default route (0/0) or a more specific route (1.1.1.1/32, 2.2.2.2/32) applies to the endpoint addresses. Once the tunnel is up, other routes may now apply -- i.e. the traffic you want in the tunnel, which might be "all traffic".

If the new route(s) cover the destination endpoint, the tunnel will fail because the endpoint will no longer be reachable -- e.g. to reach 2.2.2.2 the packet goes into the tunnel, whose destination is 2.2.2.2, which goes into the tunnel... the traffic will never leave the router. That's why the "more specifics" listed previously are *the most specific* (/32) possible route. No VPN (tunnel) or dynamic routing process can put anything more specific in the routing table, so the tunnel endpoints will always be reachable.

--

When looking at my current route table, I see:

```
      142.254.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
S        142.254.207.165 [25/0] via 174.99.112.1, GigabitEthernet0/1
```

That route was put there by DHCP, so the router always has a proper path to talk to the DHCP server that assigned my address. (hosts generally don't do that.)

Comment: So this means the packet will be constructed as follows?  | ETH | 2.2.2.2 | 2.2.2.2 | Data |
And the receiving router will terminate the tunnel on 2.2.2.2... and won't know where to forward the packet destined to 2.2.2.2?

Comment: Nothing would ever leave 1.1.1.1 because the path to 2.2.2.2 is the very tunnel to 2.2.2.2.

Comment: Why doesn't it leave? I'm not sure I understand. There is a route: 2.2.2.2 via Tunnel.  Which tells the router to encapsulate the packet in another 2.2.2.2 IP header and forward the packet out interface X with MAC address next-hop router.  I think this is still a valid route.... or am I missing something else?

Comment: If I say the only path to 2.2.2.2 is having a route that sends traffic to 2.2.2.2 as the next hop (gateway), for example `ip route 2.2.2.2 255.255.255.255 2.2.2.2`, would you expect that to work?

Comment: I see your point, but the next-hop towards the tunnel end point is already resolved in FIB, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

That problem isn't specific to GRE tunnels but applies to tunnels in general.

The most obvious example is when you create a client VPN with no split tunneling = all traffic should enter the tunnel, not just to intranet destinations.

That means that you'd want the default route to point into the tunnel - if you literally do that, the tunnel endpoint (somewhere in the Internet) instantly becomes unreachable and the tunnel collapses.

The solution is to create a specific route (that takes precedence) to the tunnel endpoint via the previous default gateway, and then you can change the default route into the tunnel.

Since that's sometimes cumbersome to roll back when the tunnel is disconnected many VPN clients create dummy 0.0.0.0/1 and 128.0.0.0/1 routes with low metric that they can simply remove afterwards.

If you run a routing protocol like OSPF through the tunnel it can 'pull' the default or the endpoint route into the tunnel - after all, the tunnel endpoint become adjacent. You need to either change advertisement (not advertise endpoint addresses or default routes), use route filtering or less-cost or more-specific static routing to circumvent that problem.

Comment: "That means that you'd want the default route to point into the tunnel - if you literally do that, the tunnel endpoint (somewhere in the Internet) instantly becomes unreachable and the tunnel collapses."  Let's say the tunnel destination is 1.1.1.1 and the tunnel endpoint is 10.0.0.1. This means, generally speaking, I will build this packet:                | Ethernet | 1.1.1.1 | 10.0.0.1 | Data |- once the tail-end of the tunnel receives this packet... it will remove 1.1.1.1 header and forward the packet to 10.0.0.1... wouldn't it? so why does this collapse?

Comment: @manishma I'm not sure I get your comment - the remote destination is usually at least one subnet. Tunnel endpoints don't adjust routes due to generic packets, you either configure static routes or use a routing protocol.